# How do you access or call the forecastValue field in Power BI and use it in DAX?

Tags: r, powerbi, dax, forecasting

I'm currently using Power Bi for forecasting, but I currently have to manually export the forecast data and use Excel to work out the MAPE (Mean Absolute Percentage Error) there. In the picture attached, you can view the forecast data as a table in Power Bi, but I can't figure out how to reference it in DAX. Is this something that's possible, aside from using R to do forecasting? Thanks!

[Forecast Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neVyF.png)